# Display WooCommerce Product Dimensions via a Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I am creating a custom layout (using Elementor) for a product - what I need is to have the dimensions of a product to display in a custom tab I have created.

Is there a shortcode for product dimensions? (some of the products are variable too if that makes a difference)

I have managed to get some code to display the long description in a shortcode (see below) however I'm not advanced enough to know what to do to get it to display product dimensions (length, width, height - ideally each one on a separate line)

Here is the long description code i found that works...

```
function custom_product_description($atts){
    global $product;

    try {
        if( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
            return wc_format_content( $product->get_description("shortcode") );
        }

        return "Product description shortcode run outside of product context";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return "Product description shortcode encountered an exception";
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'custom_product_description', 'custom_product_description' );
```

Does anyone can give me some help to display product dimensions via a shortcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following simple code snippet, to display product dimensions via a shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_dimensions', 'display_product_dimensions' );

function display_product_dimensions( $atts ){
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'product_dimensions' ) );

    if( $id == '' ) {
        global $product;

        if( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
        }
    }

    return method_exists( $product, 'get_dimensions' ) ? wc_format_dimensions($product->get_dimensions(false)) : '';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). it should works.

**USAGE:**

- On WooCommerce product single page: `[product_dimensions]`
- Anywhere with a defined Id *(for example product Id 35)*: `[product_dimensions id="35"]`

Comment: That's great and it kinda works - however it displays as N/A on my product. If it helps then the product has different variables (which in this case its a sofa, so the base sofa is the same - ie the dimensions - just has different fabrics and colours for the user). I have checked and each variable has the dimensions filled in.

It works fine for a single product... 

Also, how would i put Length/Width/Height labels before each value and if possible have them display on a separate line

Comment: I did put that some of the products were a variable product in my opening question. Thank you for your help though, i will continue my research.

Comment: Actually, your code worked perfectly - i simply added the dimensions into the shipping section and everything displays as it should. I just now need to work out how to get the labels next to the values. You've been a great help and apologies if it looked like I was taking advantage.